# dexterity item required schema.List field not validated if empty

Tags: forms, plone, dexterity

I have a field like this on my custom content type:

```
foo = schema.List(
    title=_(u'Foo'),
    value_type=schema.Choice(
        vocabulary='foo.vocab'
    ),
    required=True,
)
```

The field is rendered as in/out widget and is marked as required.

When you save the form w/ no value you don't get any error and the item it's saved even if this field has no value selected.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me...

Comment: @tisto adding "missing_value" parameter would at least give you a safe default?